# Validating signed request: signature_invalid

Tags: java, servlets, oauth, opensocial

I'm trying to validate an [OpenSocial 0.7 signed request](http://wiki.opensocial.org/index.php?title=Validating_Signed_Requests), using the sample Java code on that page. I think it should work this way, but I still get a signature_invalid error.

Main validation code:

```
 // NOTE: req = HttpServletRequest

 // check for hyves
 if (!"hyves.nl".equals(req.getParameter("oauth_consumer_key"))) {
  throw new RuntimeException("Only hyves supported");
 }

 // update hyves' certificate
 getHyvesCert(req.getParameter("xoauth_signature_publickey"));

 // construct message object
 OAuthMessage oaMessage = new OAuthMessage(req.getMethod(), getRequestUrl(req), getParameters(req));

 // validate message
 // (will throw exception if invalid)
 new SimpleOAuthValidator().validateMessage(oaMessage, new OAuthAccessor(OAUTH_CONSUMER_HYVES));
```

`OAUTH_CONSUMER_HYVES`:

```
 private static final OAuthServiceProvider OAUTH_THIS = new OAuthServiceProvider(null, null, null);
 private static final OAuthConsumer OAUTH_CONSUMER_HYVES = new OAuthConsumer(null, "hyves.nl", null, OAUTH_THIS);
```

`getHyvesCert`:

```
 public void getHyvesCert(String name) {

  synchronized(certLoadLock) {

  // in reality this is code that downloads the certificate
  // with the specified name, but this is the result
  hyvesCert = "---BEGIN CERTIFICATE---- etc...";

  OAUTH_CONSUMER_HYVES.setProperty(RSA_SHA1.X509_CERTIFICATE, hyvesCert);

  }   

 }
```

The methods `getRequestUrl` and `getParameters` are [directly copied from here](http://wiki.opensocial.org/index.php?title=Validating_Signed_Requests#Server_side_code_2).

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, do you realize that declaring `OAuthServiceProvider` and `OAuthConsumer` as servlet constants means that they're going to be shared among all requests? In other words: this is absolutely not threadsafe. You'd like to create them on every request, exactly as demonstrated in the example.

Comment: Aren't they read-only objects, after the initialisation has been done? The only change to them between requests may be an update of the cert (which in reality happens about once per year) and the code to do that is synchronized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. `getRequestUrl()` returned the wrong URL because Tomcat is behind an nginx proxy. So while the sender would use the URL "*http://example.com/bla*" to sign the request, the server was using "*http://example.com:8080/bla*" to validate it.